# Recover Couchbase password without knowing it

Tags: macos, couchbase, password-recovery

I'm working on a **mac**, downloaded the community edition for mac. Launched the app, and opened the admin console. So far so good, untill I logged out. Now I can't log in again since I've never had to set the password in the first place. It might have been set on a previous version a whole while back, but I'm not sure.

Reinstalling it doesn't work. I keep getting bounced back to the login screen.

Executing the following command as suggested in other posts and help online results in a crash of erlang

```
erl -noinput -eval 'case file:read_file("/Users/testuser/Couchbase Server.app/Contents/Resources/couchbase-core/var/lib/couchbase/config/config.dat") of {ok, B} -> io:format("~p~n", [binary_to_term(B)]) end.' -run init stop | grep cred

Crash dump was written to: erl_crash.dump
init terminating in do_boot ()
```

Any suggestions are welcome

I've been trying to put a new user in the admins section of the couchdb ini files, but they don't seem to take hold (password doesn't get hashed, which it should when these files are read)

Answer (score 6):

There is a `cbreset_password` script you can run, located in the `/Contents/Resources/couchbase-core/bin` folder of you CouchBase server App

So for me it was in `/Applications/Couchbase Server.app/Contents/Resources/couchbase-core/bin`

Simply run it and you will be able to reset the password for the `Administrator` account

Comment: If anyone is getting "Failed to obtain node connect information" Error. Try running this as sudo.

Comment: The cbreset_password script has been removed. Using your command go to your Couchbase bin folder. For mac, this is
`/Applications/Couchbase Server.app/Contents/Resources/couchbase-core/bin`
In that folder, execute this:
`./couchbase-cli reset-admin-password --new-password test123`.
Your new password will be changed to `test123`.  Here is the detailed guide: https://docs.couchbase.com/server/4.6/cli/cbcli/reset-admin-password.html

Answer (score 2):

Password is saved in plain text in config.dat binary file that located in \var\lib\couchbase folder.

You can search for string "username" and then next to it you will see "password" field and plain text value of the password.

I think there is an open defect to have better password storage mechanism in place.

The password can be changed using the couchbase-cli tool.

> shell> ./couchbase-cli cluster-init -c 127.0.0.1:8091
>   --user=[CURRENT_USERNAME] --password=[CURRENT_PASSWORD] --cluster-init-username=[NEW_USERNAME] --cluster-init-password=[NEW_PASSWORD]

Comment: i forgot both the id as well as password so what should i do ?

Answer (score 1):

On mac you can do the follwing steps

```
sudo ln -s $CB_HOME/Couchbase\ Server.app/Contents/Resources/couchbase-core/lib/ /lib
cd "$CB_HOME/Couchbase Server.app/Contents/Resources/couchbase-core/bin"
./erl -noinput -eval 'case file:read_file("[PATH TO DATA]/Library/Application Support/Couchbase/var/lib/couchbase/config/config.dat") of {ok, B} -> io:format("~p~n", [binary_to_term(B)]) end.' -run init stop | grep creds
```

CB_HOME is pointing to your Couchbase installation directory

Comment: What is the [PATH TO DATA]/Library/Application Support/Couchbase supposed to be for example? Because I don't have it (I think). I know the path the config.dat file, but it's in my install folder directly, not under another root. But even when using that path, I get a crash of erlang.

Crash dump was written to: erl_crash.dump
init terminating in do_boot ()

Comment: replace [PATH TO DATA] with your home path ~ IE: /Users/3xil3

Answer (score 1):

In case it wasn't clear since it was not fully explained in the previous answer and I'm not allowed to comment just yet. The **cbreset_password** script is a **Python script**.

For Mac OS, make sure you have Python installed. Also, there are 2 required pieces of information, the IP address of the Couchbase instance you're trying to reset and the port number.  So for a local installation, with a standard Couchbase port of 8091, the command would look something like this:

```
python /Applications/Couchbase\ Server.app/Contents/Resources/couchbase-core/bin/cbreset_password 127.0.0.1:8091
```