# Extracting couchbase password for community edition 3.0

Tags: couchbase

I'm following the instructions from https://stackoverflow.com/a/16183654/1682047 to get the default password for the web administration interface for Couchbase community edition 3.0 on Mac OSX.

The output I'm getting is:

```
{"Administrator",
 {password,
  {<<238,136,67,75,141,237,40,59,33,177,155,180,223,187,81,66>>,
   <<192,248,28,234,200,221,64,180,227,97,224,218,72,185,178,209,10,
     35,227,195>>}}}]},
```

How do I interpret this?

Alternatively is the default password listed somewhere (doesn't show up when googling)? Links to couchbase forums from Google also seem to be broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default account details are:

User: **Administrator**

Password: **password**

You can also use the [cbreset_password](http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/admin/CLI/cbreset_password_tool.html) tool to change forgotten passwords.

Answer (score 0):

Oops, this was due to me having a data directory around from a previous install.  To fix this I just deleted the existing directory at /Users/your_user_name/Library/Application Support/Couchbase.