# How to reset couchbase docker container password

Tags: docker, couchbase

I have installed 3 couchbase nodes of docker containers. After a couple of weeks when i tried to log in i could not remember my admin password. After a research i can not find a way to reset password. I am a newcomer to docker world so maybe i missed something. There is a source below but i believe that does not compromise my problem. How can i reset admin password ?

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16148207/recover-couchbase-password-without-knowing-it)

[image: visual]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to reset your admin password that I'm aware of is to use [couchbase-cli's reset-admin-password](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/cli/cbcli/couchbase-cli-reset-admin-password.html) option, which must be run locally.

Since you are in docker, one option would be to execute bash inside of Docker, and run couchbase-cli there. For instance:

```
docker exec -it db /bin/bash
```

At that point, you should have a bash prompt, and you can run couchbase-cli there.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution and wanted to share you all. After i clicked docker dashboard via docker gui i went for the container's bash then executed codes below.

```
couchbase-cli reset-admin-password --new-password 123456
```

[image]

Above Mr. Matthew clues us in with a more sophisticated way of going for container's bash.

Comment: I learned something new about the Docker UI, that's very helpful :)